# How to restrict the editors from viewing/editing pages created by admin?

Tags: admin, editor, content-restriction

In the backend, how can I restrict the editors (user with editor role) from viewing/editing pages created by admin (and/or by administrator role)?

I know that the editor role in WordPress have "edit_others_pages" capability, but I need a  function for a custom capability like: "edit_others_pages_except_admin" :)

I don't want to use a huge/complicated plugin just for that!

Thanks! I searched for a solution more then 1h :D

Answer (score 2):

This code will do the job...

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list');
function filter_posts_list($query)
{
    //$pagenow holds the name of the current page being viewed, we want to run our code only on edit.php (posts list)
    global $pagenow;

    //If the 'Editor' is logged in, exclude 'Admin's posts
    if(current_user_can('editor') && ('edit.php' == $pagenow))
    {
        //global $query's set() method for excluding admin's posts
        $query->set('author', '-1');
    }
}
```

For a detailed explanation [Read Here](http://blog.rutwick.com/display-only-the-posts-authored-by-the-current-wp-user-on-the-posts-page-in-the-back-end).

Comment: Yes, it's working if you add the get_currentuserinfo() before the "if" statement ;)

Comment: I thought `get_currentuserinfo()` won't be needed as we're using `current_user_can()`! Glad it helped you! Please accept the answer ;)

Comment: Strange thing happen... today it doesn't work anymore. I'm logged with admin and I don't see my pages (Author:Admin). I also delete the get_currentuserinfo() lines... but still no pages, I see only the pages created by editors.

Comment: Something must've gone wrong in the condition probably... can you create a paste on pastebin of your code?

Comment: I have the exact code that you post it above! I'm using the "User Switching" plugin to test this.

Comment: The code works for me, but it would be advisable to use a capability instead of a role, [as this is not guaranteed to work correctly](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can).